# move and rename multiple files of folders and subfolders into new folder

Tags: shell, directory, rename, move

so I have a huge folder structure and would like to move all existing files into 1 new folder with the prior foldernames as prefix.
**Example:**

```
Old/Test/a1/Tree.txt  
Old/Test/a1/House.txt  
Old/Test/a2/Dog.txt  
Old/Test/a3/Cat.txt  
--> New/Test_a1_Tree.txt  
--> New/Test_a1_House.txt  
--> New/Test_a2_Dog.txt  
--> New/Test_a3_Cat.txt
```

I unfortunately do not know how to automate this but would love suggestions.
Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: @oguzismail I only have rename from util-linux 2.34

Comment: Okay, do you have bash?

Comment: yes i am on Manjaro-Linux if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find Old -type f -exec bash -c '
  for p; do
    q=${p#Old/}
    echo mv "$p" "New/${q//\//_}"
  done' _ {} +
```

If you're happy with the output, remove `echo`.